How to set custom mob drop rate?
In Minecraft: Bedrock Edition is there any way to make a mob only able to drop one item and make them drop it 100% of the time? Like a spider can drop either string, a spider eye, both, or neither.
Is there any way to make it drop only string everytime and guaranteed to drop string every time and never drop nothing?
I couldn’t find anyways to do so, only found ways to delete item mobs drop and then give you a different item, but not guarantee an item is dropped in the first place

Or make an Iron Golem drop 1000 iron ingots and 200 roses upon death. (Cause why not?)

Do you know how I can?

I'm looking into it.
Cool idea, by the way.

Thank you :) I’m wanting to make a PvE arena and I’m thinking of making it be that mobs drop emeralds but the normal way to do it is by replacing what they drop with emeralds but the problem is that theres a chance they could drop nothing so I’m wondering if I can make it 100% that they drop something and only drop one item so they don’t give multiple emeralds

Please have a look at this page (of the tag you used) and add any details you can. We expect users to have tried at least something.

Welcome to Arqade! Please see our guide on asking Minecraft commands questions, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

Oh sorry about that

You can with a behavior pack! Make or get a behavior pack and add a folder called loot_tables with a folder in that called entities, with a file in that called spider.json (make sure it turns into a JSON file after you rename it). In that file, paste this:
    "pools": [
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "minecraft:string",
                    "weight": 1,
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "set_count",
                            "count": {
                                "min": 1,
                                "max": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

This will replace the vanilla loot table. To adjust the amount of string dropped, change the ”min” and ”max” values to whatever you want.

Would I have to download anything? What would I need to and how? Sry idk how behaviour packs work and stuff or how to make one

Depends on the platform. Assuming you are on pc, the built in notepad would probably work if you know how to do certain things manually. Visual Studio is made by Microsoft and has some extensions that will make your life easier, but aren't necessary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/behaviorpackfromscratch is the official website for learning how to do this stuff, and all you need before following my answer is a behavior back folder with a manifest.json, without the "dependencies" entry (plus the stuff in sqare brackets after it and the comma before it)

I also noticed in the comments of your question that you want them to drop emeralds, you can do that by replacing "name": "minecraft:string", with "name": "minecraft:emerald", and it will make them drop emeralds.
